# Accessing files on Google Storage from a Google Cloud Python job

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am loosely following a [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs/getting-started-tensorflow-estimator) to train a TensorFlow estimator on Google Cloud AI Platform.

I would like to access a directory that contains my training and evaluation data, and to this end I have copied my data files recursively to Google Storage like this:

```
gsutil cp -r data gs://name-of-my-bucket/data
```

This works fine, and `gsutil ls gs://name-of-my-bucket/data` correctly returns:

```
gs://name-of-my-bucket/data/test.json
gs://name-of-my-bucket/data/test
gs://name-of-my-bucket/data/train
```

However, calling `os.listdir(data_dir)` from a Python script raises a `FileNotFoundError` for any value of `data_dir` that I've tried so far, including `'data/'` and `'name-of-my-bucket/data/'`. Why?

I know that my Python script is being executed from the directory <strike>`/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/`</strike> `/user_dir`.

## Python code where the issue arises (edit)

Here is the code that precedes the line where the error arises, directly from the `__main__` section of my Python script:

```py
PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser()
PARSER.add_argument('--job-dir', ...)
PARSER.add_argument('--eval-steps', ...)
PARSER.add_argument('--export-format', ...)

ARGS = PARSER.parse_args()
tf.logging.set_verbosity('INFO')
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = str(tf.logging.__dict__['INFO'] / 10)

HPARAMS = hparam.HParams(**ARGS.__dict__)
```

Here is the line of code where the error arises (first line of a separate function that gets invoked right after the lines of code I have reported above):

```py
mug_dirs = [f for f in os.listdir(image_dir) if not f.startswith('.')]
```

## Logs (edit)

My logs for this job are a list of *infos* (plus 5 deprecation *warnings* related to TensorFlow), and then an *error* from the `master-replica-0` task:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec) File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/final_task.py", line 114, in <module> train_model(HPARAMS) File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/final_task.py", line 55, in train_model (train_data, train_labels) = data.create_data_with_labels("data/train/") File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/data.py", line 13, in create_data_with_labels mug_dirs = [f for f in os.listdir(image_dir) if not f.startswith('.')] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/train/'
```

... followed by another *error* from the same task (reporting non-zero exit status from my Python command), then two *infos* about clean-up, and finally an *error* from the `service` task:

```
The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec) File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/final_task.py", line 114, in <module> train_model(HPARAMS) File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/final_task.py", line 55, in train_model (train_data, train_labels) = data.create_data_with_labels("data/train/") File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trainer/data.py", line 13, in create_data_with_labels mug_dirs = [f for f in os.listdir(image_dir) if not f.startswith('.')] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/train/' To find out more about why your job exited please check the logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=1047296516162&resource=ml_job%2Fjob_id%2Fml6_run_25&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22ml_job%22%0Aresource.labels.job_id%3D%22ml6_run_25%22
```

Comment: Hi @Giorgio, as you may guess, the error means that the specified file cannot be found in the directory given by path. I believe that it would be helpful to see some **sample code** and **error message**. Please make sure that you iterate over the the folder to find the correct file script. Check out this [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm) for further details.

Comment: Hi @sllopis, thank you for the suggestion. I edited my question by correcting the directory where I believe my script is being called (`/user_dir`), and adding some sample code and logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Storage objects are a flat namespace and not contained in folders. Due to a more user-friendly experience, gsutil and the Google Cloud Storage UI will create an illusion of a hierarchical file tree. More info can be found on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork).

Now, if you are trying to read from a file object that is hosted on Cloud Storage, you may want to use the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python) to download an object to your local directory using the Cloud Storage Client Libraries. Alternatively, you may as well use the [gsutil cp](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) command, which will allow you to copy data between your local directory and Cloud Storage buckets, among other options.

Once you download a replica object from a GCS bucket in your local directory, you will be able to manipulate said file as needed.

### Update - Referencing a Cloud Storage object file - do not use `os.listdir` to access a GCS bucket object.

Because Cloud Storage is a flat namespace, a Cloud Storage bucket, `gs://my-bucket/data/test.json` will contain an object called `data/test.json` stored in the root directory of `gs://my-bucket`. Note that the object name includes `/` characters. Therefore, if you would like access, for instance, your file `test.json` in your bucket, you can check the documentation above and use `data/test.json` as the reference - the concept of folder does not exist per se. Optionally, if you needed to access your train file object, you would use `data/train` as the reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid there might be a misunderstanding: what I would like to do is to train my model on Google Cloud's AI Platform, rather than on my local machine. That's also why I have uploaded my data from my local machine to GCS. Is your answer intended for cloud training or for local training?

Comment: My answer was intially intended for local training only, but you may as well use it for cloud training by later uploading the samples to Cloud Storage. Note that this part of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs/getting-started-tensorflow-estimator#get_your_training_data) also mentions this concept and goes over the `gsutil cp` command and its features. Do not forget that you can use the `-m` flag in the `gsutil cp` command to run multiple streams in parallel, thus speeding up your transfer job when dealing with larger data sets.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, but in my question I mentioned that I have already uploaded my data files to Cloud Storage (with `gsutil cp -r data gs://name-of-my-bucket/data`). My problem is that I am apparently unable to reference this `data` directory (now present both locally and on cloud) from my Python script. I might have misunderstood your answer, but I have the impression that it doesn't exactly address this issue. Am I correct?

Comment: Okay, I see now. Because Cloud Storage is a **flat** namespace, a Cloud Storage bucket, `gs://my-bucket/data/test.json` will contain an object called `data/test.json` stored in the root directory of `gs://my-bucket`. Note that the object name includes `/` characters. Therefore, if you would like access, for instance, your file `test.json` in your bucket, you can check the documentation above and use `data/test.json` as the reference - the concept of folder does not exist per se. Optionally, if you needed to access your `train` file object, you would use `data/train` as the reference.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. Then I guess I cannot use `os.listdir` on Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: You are very welcome. Exactly @Giorgio, for future reference, if you need to interact with any Cloud APIs, in this case Cloud Storage API, you may use either of the following resources: [Google Cloud Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries), Cloud SDK - gsutil CLI, the [Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1) directly by making HTTP requests, as well as the Cloud Console Cloud Storage dashboard. If this information helped you, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer for greater visibility to other users.

Comment: I will gladly mark your answer as accepted. And, if you don't mind, I would like to edit your answer by explicitly saying that the issue from where this whole problem arose is the use of `os.listdir`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the tensorflow API to get all files in a directory on GCP. You can refer to their documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/glob

For example, if you want to get all json files under your GCP, you can use this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

json_files = tf.io.gfile.glob("gs://name-of-my-bucket/data/"+"*.json")
```